# Joining dataframes and multiplying values of similarly named columns

Tags: r

Two dataframes where columns have names as dates. I want to join both the dataframes where the value of the date columns should be the product of both date columns of the dataframes.

Both dataframes have different no of rows and columns.

[image: Both dataframes and the resultant set]

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. My date variables all start with date, so you will have to adjust your pivot_longer syntax for selecting which columns to spread long. Normally when posting a question it's nice to upload a sample data set, not just post a photo.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#create data
df1 <- data.frame(skill = seq(3), id = seq(3), date1 = rnorm(3), date2 = rnorm(3), date3 = rnorm(3))
df2 <- data.frame(skill = seq(4), id = seq(4), date1 = rnorm(4), date2 = rnorm(4))

#combine data
df <- merge.data.frame(x = df1, y = df2, by = c("skill", "id" ) , all = T) %>% #merge, option all because dataframes have dif num of obs
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("date"),
               names_to = c("date", "num"),
               names_sep = "[.]") %>% #make data long
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(skill, date) %>%
  mutate(value = prod(value, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% #na true because dataframes have different dates
  select(-num) %>%
  unique() %>% #drop duplicates
  pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = value) #make data wide again
```

Edit, fixed bug when date variables are not the same, and changed from sum to product, like you asked for originally

Answer (score 0):

1. The main work is to bring the data into the correct shape
2. I have coded step by step, so you can follow my approach -> there a faster ways!
3. After getting the correct shape of table 1 and table 2 it is easy to join and get the product rowise by grouping!

```
library(dplyr)

# your raw data as matrix

col_names <- c("Skill", "Work Code", "Product", "Base", "Q1 Job Time", "Q2 onwards Job Time", "31-12-2019", "7-1-2020", "14-1-2020", "21-1-2020", "28-1-2020", "4-2-2020", "11-2-2020")
a <- c("Skill1", "W1", "P1", "1.6", "2.7", "0.5", "1.6", "2.7", "0.5", "1.6", "2.7", "0.5", "1.6")
b <- c("Skill2", "W2", "P2", "1.7", "2.1", "3.4", "1.7", "2.1", "3.4", "11", "2.1", "3.4", "1.7")
c <- c("Skill3", "W3", "P3", "1.8", "3.5", "1.2", "1.8", "3.5", "1.2", "1.8", "3.5", "1.2", "1.8")
table1 <- rbind(a,b,c)
colnames(table1) <- col_names

col_names2 <- c("Skill", "Work Code", "Product", "31-12-2019", "7-1-2020", "14-1-2020", "21-1-2020", "28-1-2020", "4-2-2020", "11-2-2020") 
a2 <- c("Skill1", "W1", "P1", "1.6", "2.7", "0.5", "1.6", "2.7", "0,6", "1.6")
b2 <- c("Skill2", "W2", "P2", "1.7", "2.1", "3.4", "1.7", "2.1", "3.4", "1.7")
c2 <- c("Skill3", "W3", "P3", "1.8", "3.6", "1.2", "1.8", "3.5", "1.2", "1.8")
table2 <- rbind(a2,b2,c2)
colnames(table2) <- col_names2

# assign matrix to dataframe
table1 <- as.data.frame(table1)
table2 <- as.data.frame(table2)

# change from character to numeric the columns with date
sapply(table1, class)
cols.num <- c("31-12-2019", "7-1-2020", "14-1-2020", "21-1-2020", "28-1-2020", "4-2-2020", "11-2-2020")
table1[cols.num] <- sapply(table1[cols.num],as.numeric)
table2[cols.num] <- sapply(table2[cols.num],as.numeric)

# remove uneccessary columns
table1 <- table1 %>% 
  select(-"Base", -"Q1 Job Time", -"Q2 onwards Job Time")

# calculate desired table
Table_desired = table1 %>% 
  full_join(table2) %>% 
  group_by(Skill,  `Work Code`, Product) %>% 
  #summarise(across(everything(), sum))
summarise_all(funs(prod(.,na.rm = T)))
```